# phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04 downloads a file instead of opening login page

Tags: 14.04, apache2, phpmyadmin

I have installed apache, php and phpmyadmin with this command in Ubuntu 14.04

```
apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql php5-imap phpmyadmin php5-cli php5-cgi libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec php-pear php-auth php5-mcrypt mcrypt php5-imagick imagemagick libapache2-mod-suphp libruby libapache2-mod-python php5-curl php5-intl php5-memcache php5-memcached php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl memcached snmp
```

Follwing [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4).

Now every php-file in `/var/www/html` runs and works :), 
but localhost/phpmyadmin downloads a file instead of opening the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe php isn't enabled yet. Try the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

This [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Phpmyadmin_and_mysql-workbench) also discusses troubleshooting phpmyadmin. It is referring to a 404 error opening http://localhost/phpmyadmin but this might still apply here:

> ```
> $ gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> ```
>
> Include the following line at the bottom of the file, save and quit.
>
> ```
> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
> ```